# How to integrate toggle hamburger animation in mobile menu, WordPress, JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, menu, hamburger-menu

I want to integrate toggle hamburger animation for my mobile menu WordPress website. I was following a tutorial where on the JavaScript code the "Open" and "Close" buttons are two separate icons. I have a hamburger menu but I cant figure out how the "toggle" function works and I cannot make it work. I can connect them so that the menu opens, but after that it cannot be closed. Any help will be appreciated. Bellow is my code for my full screen menu (no toggle). Thank you!

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

var $ = jQuery
    leavePage = false

var placeImages = function(){
    
$('.f-menu .elementor-icon-list-item').each(function(i){
    
    var offset = 20, 
        x = $(this).find('.elementor-icon-list-text').width() + offset,
        y = $(this).offset().top - $('.f-menu .elementor-icon-list-item').eq(0).offset().top
        
    console.log($(window).width())
        
    if( $(window).width() < 768 ) { x = 0 }
    
    $('.menu-image .elementor-gallery-item').eq(i).css('transform', 'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)')
    
    $('.menu-image').css('top', $('.f-menu .elementor-icon-list-item').eq(0).offset().top - $('.f-menu-section').offset().top)
})
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    
placeImages()

var menuStart = 0.8;
    menuDiff = 0.1;

$('.f-menu-section .elementor-icon-list-item').each(function(){
    
    $(this).css('transition-delay', menuStart + 's')
    menuStart += menuDiff
})

var menuHovered = false

$('.f-menu .elementor-icon-list-item').hover(function(){
    
    var i = $(this).index()
   $('.menu-image .elementor-gallery-item').eq(i).addClass('active')
   $('.menu-image').css('z-index', 1)
   menuHovered = true
}, function(){
    $('.menu-image .elementor-gallery-item').removeClass('active')
    menuHovered = false
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(menuHovered) return
        $('.menu-image').css('z-index', -1)
        
    },300)
})

$('.f-open').on('click', function(){
    $('.f-menu-section').addClass('active')
})

$('.f-close').on('click', function(){
    $('.f-menu-section').removeClass('active')
})


$('.f-menu-section .elementor-icon-list-item a').on('click', function(){
    
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(leavePage) return
        $('.f-menu-section').addClass('faded')
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.f-menu-section').removeClass('active')
        },200)
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.f-menu-section').removeClass('faded')
        },1000+200)
    },50)
})

})

window.onbeforeunload = () => {
    leavePage = true
    
}

$(window).on('load resize', placeImages)

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to use template icons like FontAwesome or others, So that you dont need to make a seperate button. Probably use a variable `isOpened` and if its opened switch the class to opened and switch the icons. Not seperate them buttons.

```
let isOpened = false;
if (isOpened){
$('.youricon').class = "fa-solid fa-x"
}
```

Here im using fontAwesome, you can always choose an alternative.

> https://fontawesome.com/